# What does this.handleClick on the LEFT side of the = sign do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, es6-class

I'm confused about how `this` is used in a ES6 constructor.

First, I understood the following (see ex below):
 - We use `this.height = height;` to add a new `instance variable`.
 - Adding a new instance method using `className() {...}`, and adding a static class using `static className() {...}`.
 - Using `this` to refer to an instance method like `this.calcArea()` in the getter below.

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  get area() {   // Getter
    return this.calcArea();
  }
  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
  static staticMethod() {
    return 'static method has been called.';
  }
}
```

Nevertheless, when I saw the React example attached below, `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` in ln-7 puzzles me.  I understood `this.handleClick.bind(this);`.  The part I have doubts is `this.handleClick` that's on the `LEFT` side of the `=` sign.  this.handleClick looks like it's making an `instance variable` called handleClick.  I look at it that way b/c of `this.height = height;` in the previous example.

My question: Is my thought wrong?  or can anyone explain what `this.handleClick` on the `LEFT` side of the `=` sign do?

[image]

Comment: It's replacing / overwriting the original `handleClick` method with the one bound to the class context. Just like `class A { a = 1; constructor(){ this.a = this.a + 1 } }` - first you define a property, then update it with a new value (that can the original value to create the new one).

Comment: BTW to avoid the `bind`ing boilerplate in constructors you can use `handleClick = () => {}` which is automatically bound to the class context. I think it requires https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to bind the function to component instance. Check it out [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-constructor-es2015). It is used for ES5 functions. It you use ES6 functions you would not need to use find.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // need binding for es5
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }

  handleClick2 = () => {
    console.log('click happened (es6)');
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
         <button onClick={this.handleClick2}>Click Me 2</button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:** `this` keyword is used to assign values to object instance in case of basic javascript class. Similarly it is being used for react class.

Comment: Naveen, you missed my question.  I stated that I understood the binding part.  The part I'm confused of is what this.handleClick on the LEFT side of the = sign do.

Comment: this.handleClick overrides the existing function property by adding this binding t previous this.handleClick and replacing it.